# Node.js Express middleware: app.param vs app.use

Tags: node.js, express

In the chain of calls inside Express middleware, do the app.param methods always get called before app.use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested with this program changing the order of `app.use` vs `app.param` with express 4.10.2. The param always runs first, which makes sense because the route handler expects to be able to do `req.params.foo` and in order for that to work the param handlers need to have run.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use("/:file", function (req, res) {
  console.log("@bug route", req.params.file);
  res.send();
});

app.param("file", function (req, res, next, val) {
  console.log("@bug param", val);
  next();
});



app.listen(3003);
```

Run this and test with `curl localhost:3003/foo` and you get the output:

```
@bug param foo
@bug route foo
```

Comment: console logging is async, so for the sake of completeness adding a timestamp (`Date.now()` or `process.hrtime()`) to `console.log` yields the same results when ordering by time.

Comment: That's not entirely true. It's a single stream and the output is guaranteed to appear on the console in the same order it is passed to console.log(). If stdout order was not guaranteed, all manner of chaos would ensue and you could not write data reliably to stdout. The above is fine and there is no chance of misleading stdout.

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm stuck in forked children "mode" where order from different child processes is not guaranteed when writing to the console.

Comment: That's good to know; the docs suggest otherwise so this is a good "gotcha"

Answer (score 2):

You can test it through logging, but I'm reasonably certain that in 4.0, everything is called in the order it's declared when you set up your app.

Comment: this answer differs from another answer. what you said would be reasonable, but it looks like app.params always run first in Express 4

Comment: Good to know; the docs say the 'use' statements are in order, and with .param being setup on a Router (which is then 'used') it is not intuitive.